# Upload or Download from/to ftp server: Android Client

Tags: android, ftp

I'm working on android project to test FTP functions both upload or download files.
Here's my first try code based on [this](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/) tutorial:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

        // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
        ftp.connect("ftp.olympe-network.com", 21, "username", "password");


        // Set binary mode.
        ftp.bin();

        // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
        ftp.cwd("web");

        // Upload some files.
        ftp.stor(new File("shirt.jpg"));
        //ftp.stor(new File("comicbot-latest.png"));

        // You can also upload from an InputStream, e.g.
        ftp.stor(new FileInputStream(new File("shirt.jpg")), "shirt.jpg");
        /*ftp.stor(someSocket.getInputStream(), "blah.dat");
        */

        // Quit from the FTP server.
        ftp.disconnect();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // Jibble.
    }
}
```

My shirt.jpg file is store in the main project folder.i am using emulator not a physical device. I didn't have error in my log, but the file is not uploaded.

Then, i changed to another approach:

```
private void loadLogs() {
    //radBtn.addView(null);
    new processTask().execute();
}
private class processTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(activitiMain.this);
     private TextView log; 
     private  Spinner s;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        Dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        try {
        SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String ipaddr = myPref.getString("etServer", "");
        String port= myPref.getString("port", "21");
        String logFile= myPref.getString("logfname", "error_log");
        String filePath= myPref.getString("path", "/public_html");
        String uname= myPref.getString("uname", "");
        String pass= myPref.getString("pass", "");
        client.connect(ipaddr,21);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        boolean login = client.login(uname, pass);
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(filePath);
        System.out.println(client.printWorkingDirectory());

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = null;
        sv = new ScrollView(activitiMain.this);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        sv.setLayoutParams(LP_FF);
        LinearLayout loglay  =  new LinearLayout(activitiMain.this);
        loglay.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );  //FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();                              
        ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter =new ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

             adapter.add("Select File");*/      
            //s = new (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
            s = new Spinner(activitiMain.this);
            for (int i = 0; i < ftpFiles.length; i++) { 
                String fname =ftpFiles[i].getName();
                Log.i("FTP", "File " +i +" : "+fname);
                       name.add(fname);
                        long length = ftpFiles[i].getSize();
                        //adapter2.add(ftpFiles[i].getName());
                        //String readableLength = FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize( length );
                        ///System.out.println( name + ":\t\t" + readableLength );  
                    }
            //String [] strArray =null;
            //strArray.toArray(name);
            String [] files = name.toArray(new String[name.size()]);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,files);  
             adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
             s.setAdapter(adapter2);  
             loglay.addView(s);

         Log.i("Files", ftpFiles.toString());
            for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles) {
                String fileName = ftpFile.getName(); 
                if (fileName.equals(logFile)){
                     try {
                         InputStream stream = client.retrieveFileStream(fileName);                             
                         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
                         //line = reader.readLine();


                         while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null && line.trim().length()>0) {
                                //System.out.println(line);
                             log = new TextView(activitiMain.this);
                                String trail = line; 
                                log.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                log.setPadding(10, 5, 0, 5);
                                log.setText(trail);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                loglay.addView(log);    
                            }
                         sv.addView(loglay);
                     } finally {
                         if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
                     }
                }
            }
               client.logout();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(sv);
        }
```

In my preference screen, i specified the ftp server parameters, but i got also an error in my logcat:

```
    05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1969)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1845)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:217)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1658)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at com.sam.remote.activitiMain$processTask.onPostExecute(activitiMain.java:160)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at com.sam.remote.activitiMain$processTask.onPostExecute(activitiMain.java:1)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-27 18:36:38.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(585):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first attempt here when you say your file shirt.jpg is stored in your main project folder I don't think that your code will find that once deployed to the device, you will probably either have to manually store that file on the device as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

or you can upload the shirt.jpg file (trough ADP) first to your apps shared directory as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

then try to read it and FTP it.

Oh yes also my experience with saving files on Android and then E-mailing them, use an actual device to test because the emulator does not provide you with the network connections that you need.

Comment: Thanks, my second try worked for download. I put shirt.jpg in FTP server and i can download it, But the upload didn't work yet, i put shirt.jpg in res/raw, trying also in drawable, but i think my code didn't find it to upload

Answer (score 0):

private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask<DocumentFile, Void, Void> {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(DocumentFile... documentFiles) {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(SERVER);
            ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // Upload the file from the device to the FTP server
            uploadFile(ftpClient, documentFiles[0]);
            isUploadSuccessful = true;
            // Download the file from the FTP server to the app's private files directory
            downloadFile(ftpClient);

            // Disconnect after the upload and download
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void uploadFile(FTPClient ftpClient, DocumentFile pickedFile) throws IOException {
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        // Create an InputStream for the picked file
        try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedFile.getUri())) {
            // Specify the remote file name on the server
            ftpClient.storeFile(REMOTE_FILE_NAME, inputStream);
            showToast("File uploaded successfully to: " + REMOTE_FILE_NAME);
        }
    }

    private void downloadFile(FTPClient ftpClient) throws IOException {
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        // Specify the remote file name on the server
        String remoteFileName = REMOTE_FILE_NAME;

        // Create an InputStream to read the file from the FTP server
        try (InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFileName)) {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // Save the file to the app's private files directory
                saveToFile(inputStream);
                showToast("File downloaded successfully to: " + getFilesDir() + "/" + remoteFileName);
            } else {
                showToast("Error downloading file: " + ftpClient.getReplyString());
            }
        }
    }
```

use this code snippet in your code

private static final String SERVER = "115.111.229.10";
private static final String USERNAME = "rnd";
private static final String PASSWORD = "rnd123";    replace these values with your values

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

on which line happened the exception? double click on the error message and try to debug/post again